# Smallest prime of the form $\phi_{21209}(n)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, cyclotomic-polynomials

> What is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $$\phi_{21209}(n)=\frac{(n^{21209}-1)(n-1)}{(n^{127}-1)(n^{167}-1)}$$ is a prime number ?

I chose the $21209$ th cyclotomic polynomial because the smallest possible prime factor is $$2\ 290\ 573$$ and because of this , I expected to find a prime relatively early.

However, I did not find a prime for $n\le 6\ 500$. If there actually is no prime upto this $n$, a prime of this form must have more than $79\ 000$ digits.

Can anyone doublecheck the range, find a prime or give a reference in the case someone has done this already ?

Comment: Do you mean $n^{127}-1$ instead of $n^{127-1}$?

Comment: @KentaS Yes, I meant that

Comment: Maybe you know this already, but even if you find a prime of this form (with more than a few tens of thousands of digits), it's unlikely that you'll be able to *prove* its primality, because there's no obvious way to factor $\phi_{21209}(n) \pm 1$.

Comment: @RaviFernando That is no problem. A prp is enough